# Print markdown file from command line

Tags: command-line, printing, formatting, markdown

I was looking for a way to print a **markdown** file from command line. I usually use `lp` for simple text files; I want to use something like that, but for **markdown**.

Also it would be great that this printing could take care of hyphenation (my actual approach to this does not).

In a more general way it would be fantastic to print many more types of files from command line.

---

**Edit:** Notice that it's possible to add a mime type to the `lp` command. For example:

`lp -o document-format=text/x-markdown file.md`

Of course the problem with this is that the my printing system (cups) doesn't allow this type of document.

---

***Solution:*** A friend told me about a way to accomplish this. A series of pipes.
`markdown file.md` -> .md to .html
`iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1` -> utf-8 to iso-8859-1
`html2ps` -> html to postscript
`lp` -> print

**Finally**

```
markdown file.md | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 | html2ps | lp
```

Does the trick

---

***The bad:*** This *does not* accomplish the *hyphenation* part (at least I don't think so). My friend told me that in order to accomplish this is better to use **`pandoc`** to convert a file from **markdown** to **LaTeX** and then print that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution***: A friend told me about a way to accomplish this. A series of pipes.
`markdown file.md` -> .md to .html
`iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1` -> utf-8 to iso-8859-1
`html2ps` -> html to postscript
`lp` -> print

**Finally**

```
markdown file.md | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 | html2ps | lp
```

Does the trick

***The bad***: This does not accomplish the hyphenation part (at least I don't think so). My friend told me that in order to accomplish this is better to use `pandoc` to convert a file from markdown to LaTeX and then print that.

Answer (score 0):

There are command-line tools for converting markdown to text; you could then pipe it to something like lp or a2ps or similar.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue at all, if I wanted to print a plain text file I would print a plain text file. If I make a markdown file, I expect to get formatted output.